# Make computer boot from an existing installation of 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, partitioning, data-recovery

I am trying to restore my Ubuntu 18.04 machine after one of two its hard disks failed. The remaining SSD disk still has all (or most) files from the operating system with my programs and data. The failed disk which stored some data has been replaced with another HDD, 466 GB. Just wondering if there is a way to make the machine boot from the existing installation of Ubuntu without reinstalling everything from scratch, because it would save a ton of time and effort.

`sudo lsblk` gives the following output:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0   1.8G  1 loop /rofs
sda           8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
sdb           8:16   1  14.4G  0 disk /cdrom
├─sdb1        8:17   1   1.8G  0 part
└─sdb2        8:18   1   2.3M  0 part
nvme0n1     259:0    0   477G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   260M  0 part
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  96.7G  0 part
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0  1000M  0 part
├─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0 310.6G  0 part
├─nvme0n1p6 259:6    0     1G  0 part
├─nvme0n1p7 259:7    0     1M  0 part
└─nvme0n1p8 259:8    0  67.5G  0 part
```

The operating system files are on partition nvme0n1p5 (ext4). sda is the new HDD. sdb is a USB stick with the Ubuntu image.

The remaining partitions are:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1  EFI system partition, fat32  SYSTEM_DRV
/dev/nvme0n1p2  Microsoft reserved partition
/dev/nvme0n1p3  Basic data partition  ntfs  Windows-SSD
/dev/nvme0n1p6                        ext4
/dev/nvme0n1p5                        ext4
/dev/nvme0n1p7                        unknown
/dev/nvme0n1p8                        ext4
/dev/nvme0n1p4  Basic data partition  ntfs  WINRE_DRV
```

The remainder of the OEM Window OS is not important, it is never used.

Thanks a lot for your advice, it will be very gratefully appreciated!

Comment: From what you have told us there is probably nothing to stop the system booting. What happens when you try to boot? What errors do you get? You may need to temporarily hash out the entry in fstab for the old drive but without error messages it’s hard to say.

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: thanks, @oldfred! here is the pastebin link: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/g9W9TNDBvY/

Comment: You booted live installer in BIOS mode. Reboot in UEFI mode & rerun report after fixes. Post in question above. Only boot in UEFI mode. You show 2 separate installs 18.04. And both ESP - efi system partition and bios_grub. You should never boot in BIOS mode, so bios_grub would never be used. Change p5 from ESP to Linux, you can only have one ESP per drive. You also have mount of /dev/sda3 which was old drive? Change to # at beginning of line as that may slow boot a lot. Only use gpt partitioning on new drive, it looks unpartitioned. And mount data with UUID or labels not device like /dev/sda3.

Comment: thank you, @oldfred! here is the new pastebin: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/SJP7Y662XW/
The installation I care about is in /dev/nvme0n1p5

Comment: You did not do fixes first. It still shows p5 as an ESP.  And line 254 does not have # as first char to convert to comment. And while in live installer set sdb as gpt. With gparted select gpt under device, advanced over msdos(MBR) default partitioning before starting.

Comment: thanks a million, @oldfred! You were absolutely right, the problem was with /dev/sda3. After commenting it out, the old Ubuntu installation booted well. Problem solved now, thank you for your time and help!